# Create a POST body using Google Apps Script

Tags: post, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, urlfetch

I'm trying to create a Google Apps Script that adds a new owner to the user's Google calendar. The first code block below works correctly (returns the calendar ACL in JSON format). How can I add a new user to the acl using Google Apps Script? The second code block shows my attempt to insert a new rule into the acl.

```
function getCalendarACL() {

  // Get Calendar ID, script user's email, and the API Key for access to Calendar API
  var calId = 'abc123@group.calendar.google.com';
  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var API_KEY = '012345abc123';  

  // Get authorization to access the Google Calendar API
  var apiName = 'calendar';
  var scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
  var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_(apiName, scope);

  // Get the authorization information and the given calendar
  fetchArgs.method = 'GET';

  // Get the requested content (the ACL for the calendar)
  var base = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/';
  var url = base + calId + '/acl?key=' + API_KEY;
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getContentText();
  Logger.log(content); 
}

function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");

  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

Here's the second code block that returns server error 400 ("parse error"):

```
 function insertRule() {

  // Get Calendar ID, script user's email, and the API Key for access to Calendar API
  var calId = 'abc123@group.calendar.google.com';
  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var API_KEY = '012345abc123'; 
  var newUserEmail = 'person@gmail.com'; 

  // Get authorization to access the Google Calendar API
  var apiName = 'calendar';
  var scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
  var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_(apiName, scope);

  // Get the authorization information and the given calendar
  fetchArgs.method = 'GET';

  // Create the POST request body
  var rawXML = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' " +
           "xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007'>" +
           "<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'" +
           "term='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessRule'/>" +
           "<gAcl:scope type='user' value='"+newUserEmail+"'></gAcl:scope>" +
           "<gAcl:role='writer'>" +
           "</gAcl:role>" +
           "</entry>";

  // Get the requested content (the ACL for the calendar)
  var base = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/';
  var url = base + calId + '/acl?key=' + API_KEY;
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getContentText();
  Logger.log(content); 
}
```

Comment: How did you go with this @KarBytes? Did the encoding of the email variable in the answer below solve your problem of adding a user or did you manage to solve it in some other way?

Comment: Encoding the email variable didn't change anything. I think the rawXML might need headers. I got a server error 404 when I used version 2 of the API: `var base = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v2/calendars/';`

Answer (score 1):

I would encode the newUserEmail variable like this encodeURIComponent(newUserEmail) when making the rawXML string and then retry.

Answer (score 1):

You are using:

```
  fetchArgs.method = 'GET';
```

but at the Acl:insert page found [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert) says this:

> **HTTP Request**
>
> ```
> POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/acl
> ```

So, it should be,

```
  fetchArgs.method = 'POST';
```