# How to add other users to a calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add a user programatically to some Google calendars via Google Apps Script. Basically, it's for when a new teacher starts, I want to add them to the 5 calendars we have, without having to do it manually (note, these are personal accounts).

I want something like the subscribeToCalendar method but to add a user that isn't the active one, i.e. me. The script already collects their email address and I have the calendar IDs. I've looked in the Google Calendar documentation and can't find any way to do this.

I have also found this in the Google Calendar API documentation which talks about updating the role to for example, "reader", which is want I want, but I have no idea how this is implemented with Google Apps Script, as the examples on the page are Java, etc.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/update#examples

I found this question which I think is in the right direction but seems awfully complex for just adding a user to the calendar:
[Create a POST body using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694271/create-a-post-body-using-google-apps-script)

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.
Baz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're heading in the right direction, you need to use the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) (That must be [enabled before use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). In the Script Editor select Resources > Advanced Google services... and then enable it in the Google Developers Console.)

Once enabled you can [share the calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing#sharing_calendars) using the [ACL: insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert), here's an example:

```
function myFunction() {

  var calendarIds = ['CAL_ID_1','CAL_ID_2','CAL_ID_3','CAL_ID_4','CAL_ID_5'];
  var userEmail = 'USER_EMAIL';
  var resource = {
      'scope': {
        'type': 'user',
        'value': userEmail
      },
      'role': 'reader'
    };

  for (var i = 0; i < calendarIds.length; i++) {
    Calendar.Acl.insert(resource, calendarIds[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're a star! This works perfectly. The only extra thing I added was that as I'm sharing 5 calendars, there are 5 calendarId variables (e.g. calendarId1, calendarId2, etc. Plus the last line "Calendar.Acl.insert(resource, calendarId1); is repeated 5 times, with each line referring to the different calendar variables. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @BazR You can define the calendar ids inside an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) then just loop through the values, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @ocordova Hadn't thought of that, that makes it much simpler and cleaner code.